# Need help checking over angular ui-router code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to create a portfolio in angular, and can't seem to get the routing correct. I double checked with an app I had made previously, and can't seem to find anything. When I compile, there are no errors logged in the console. Could someone check if my code is properly laid out?

the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>my portfolio</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">

  <!-- <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css"> -->
  </head>

  <body np-app="myPort">
    <div id="navigation-bar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#/home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/projects">My Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div ui-view></div>

    <!-- loading angular frameworks -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!-- app js stuff -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

the module

```
angular.module('myPort', ['ui.router'])

.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'partials/bio/index.html',
          })

        .state('projects', {
            url: '/projects',
            templateUrl: 'partials/projects/index.html',
          })

        .state('contact', {
            url: '/contact',
            templateUrl: 'partials/contact/index.html',
        })

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
}]);
//no controllers linked for troubleshooting
```

Comment: can you create a plnkr

Comment: What problem are you having with it exactly?

Comment: jquery.js should be above angularjs, if that makes any difference.

Comment: The templates aren't loading in the ui-view. To test this, I supplemented "templateUrl" with just "template" to makes sure my paths were correct.

Comment: What are the absolute paths to the views?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/3cmVC7pRUJrnhk1miuJM?p=preview

Comment: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3 ?

Comment: There is no base URL for the templates.

Comment: prashkr could you explain to me? I'm still new at coding in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a spelling mistake while defining `ng-app`.

Change `<body np-app="myPort>"` to `<body ng-app="myPort>"`

Comment: That did the trick! Not sure how I could have missed something like that jeez

Comment: `p` and `g` kind of looks similar :)